# Consecutive words match in a dataset

Tags: c#, algorithm, strings, hash-map

I have written an algorithm to do consecutive word match in a dataset

The input is a `dataset` (list of textlines) and I want to scan that and return repeated word(s) in the dataset along with some metadata like the strings (lines) they matched at.

I am having hard time to wrap my mind around a better approach to hand the consecutive words match. What I have so far is:

- `hashtable` datastructure
- I compute the permutations of each sentence's words. So complexity is n+ (n*avg words count). e.g: `abc def gg ww` will produce the following permutations

  -- `abc def`
  -- `abc def gg`
  -- `abc def gg ww`
  -- `def gg`
  -- `def gg ww`
  -- `gg ww`
- I store every possible word combination from each sentence in a dictionary with value of 1
- if a word combination exists in the dictionary, I increase the value by 1
- using stringBuilder to avoid string immutability
- I refine my dictionary at the end to remove any items that has value of 1

I am curios if:
1) this can be improved
2) are there any other datastructures/algo I can use to do the consecutive word matching on a text blob

It is C# now, but we are considering python or Go as well.

```
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> ConsecutiveMatches { get; set; }

public void Load(List<string> dataset)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Count; i++)
    {
        var sentence = dataset[i];
        var words = sentence.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        BuildConsecutiveMatches(words, sentence);
    }

    RefineConsecutiveMatches();
}

private void BuildConsecutiveMatches(string[] words, string sentence)
{
    BuildConsecutiveMatchesRecursive(words, 0, sentence);
}

private void BuildConsecutiveMatchesRecursive(string[] words, int index, string sentence)
{
    if (index >= words.Length - 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    var builder = new StringBuilder(words[index]);
    builder.Append(' ');

    for (int i = index + 1; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        builder.Append(words[i]);
        var permutation = builder.ToString();
        if (ConsecutiveMatches.TryGetValue(permutation, out var matches))
        {
            ConsecutiveMatches[permutation].Add(sentence);
        }
        else
        {
            ConsecutiveMatches.Add(permutation, new List<string> { sentence });
        }
        builder.Append(' ');
    }

    BuildConsecutiveMatchesRecursive(words, ++index, sentence);
}

private void RefineConsecutiveMatches()
{
    ConsecutiveMatches = ConsecutiveMatches.Where(pair => pair.Value.Count >= 2)
                            .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key,
                                        pair => pair.Value);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works because this line `var words = sentence.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` appears to be invalid.

Comment: which part? i am on netcore2.1 fyi

Answer (score 2):

The data structure you want is called a trie.  It's often used with letters in the nodes, for doing word search (finding anagrams and so on); in your case the keys would be words and the values would be sub-tries and arrays of line numbers or other metadata.

Given this input:

```
cat dog pig
dog pig cow
```

You'd make a structure like:

```
{
    cat: {
      dog: {
        pig: { "#": [ 1 ] },
        "#": [ 1 ]
      },
      "#": [ 1 ]
    },
    dog: {
      pig: { 
        cow: { "#": [ 2 ] },
        "#": [ 1, 2 ]
      },
      "#": [ 1, 2 ]
    },
    pig: { 
      cow: { "#": [ 2 ] },
      "#": [ 1, 2 ]
    },
    cow: { "#": [ 2 ] },
}
```

Comment: i am trying to wrap my head around how is this more performant than the hashtable implementation? also, in line 11 how were you able to determine that pig appeared in sentence  #1 without traversing the trie?

Comment: It's not more performant.  The point is that it's equal performance with \$O(n^2)\$ storage while the hash uses \$O(n^3)\$ storage.   `pig` is added to the trie as you traverse the text.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public Dictionary<string, List<string>> ConsecutiveMatches { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
> ```

I wouldn't allow public access to the result in this way, because I wouldn't want clients to be able to manipulate the result of the search directly. Instead I would make this result data be private and then expose it via a public read only method or property either as an `IEnumerable<>` or as an `IReadOnlyDictionary<>`:

```
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> matches = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, List<string>> GetResult()
{
  return new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, List<string>>(matches.Where(m => m.Value.Count > 1).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value));
}
```

In this way you ensure that the result is valid and consistent if you need it to be used more than once.

Another common way could be to implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but here that is IMO wrong because of the call to `Load(...)`. A pattern like (for the different naming see below):

```
  ConsecutiveMatcher matcher = new ConsecutiveMatcher();
  matcher.Search(data);
  foreach (var result in matcher.GetResult())
  {
     ...
  }
```

is more intuitive than:

```
  ConsecutiveMatcher matcher = new ConsecutiveMatcher();
  matcher.Search(data);
  foreach (var result in matcher)
  {
     ...
  }
```

---

> ```
> public void Load(List<string> dataset)
> {
> ```

If this method is called more than once, you'll have to have a flag to indicate if the new data is to be appended to existing data or the cache should be reset:

```
public void Search(List<string> dataset, bool append = false)
{
  if (dataset == null || dataset.Count == 0) return;  // Or throw?

  if (!append) matches.Clear();
```

and as shown, you should validate the input.

---

> ```
>     var words = sentence.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
> ```

You have to refine the way you split into words:

In this sentence `"this world in this world."` the two `"this world"` occurrences are not matched by your way to split into words because of the punctuation.

On the other hand are `"Hello World"` `"Hello. World"` to be regarded as consecutively equal?

Depending on how you define a word and "consecutive", you could use a `regex` pattern like:

```
      string pattern = @"(?<word>\b\w+\b)(?<space>[\W]*)";
```

and then split the string by a `Regex` match:

```
        var words = Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["word"].Value).ToArray();
```

Whether the above pattern is suitable for your culture or needs you'll have to decide, but it could be a place to start.

---

> `permutation`

strictly speaking the strings you are building are not permutations but 
 `sub strings` or `prefix strings`.

---

> ```
>     if (ConsecutiveMatches.TryGetValue(permutation, out var matches))
>     {
>       ConsecutiveMatches[permutation].Add(sentence);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>       ConsecutiveMatches.Add(permutation, new List<string> { sentence });
>     }
> ```

This is a little awkward construct. Why not use the maybe found `matches`:

```
    if (!ConsecutiveMatches.TryGetValue(permutation, out var matches))
    {
      matches= new List<string>();
      ConsecutiveMatches[permutation] = matches;
    }

    matches.Add(sentence);
```

---

All in all it's not a bad implementation, but there is a major problem in that it builds up a large dictionary of strings with large data sets and the deconstruct - reconstruct of prefix strings is time expensive. As "Oh My Goodness" states, a `trie` as data structure is more efficient in respect to memory and probably also time wise - for large data sets at least.

---

Below is an edition of your code with the above comments implemented. I've also renamed things a little bit in my flavor:

```
  class ConsecutiveWordMatcher
  {
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> matches = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public void Search(List<string> dataset, bool append = false)
    {
      if (dataset == null || dataset.Count == 0) return;

      if (!append) matches.Clear();

      string pattern = @"(?<word>\b\w+\b)(?<space>[\W]*)";

      for (int i = 0; i < dataset.Count; i++)
      {
        var sentence = dataset[i];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sentence)) continue;

        var words = Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["word"].Value).ToArray();

        BuildConsecutiveMatches(words, sentence);
      }
    }

    private void BuildConsecutiveMatches(string[] words, string sentence)
    {
      BuildConsecutiveMatchesRecursive(words, 0, sentence);
    }

    private void BuildConsecutiveMatchesRecursive(string[] words, int index, string sentence)
    {
      if (index >= words.Length - 1)
      {
        return;
      }

      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(words[index]);
      builder.Append(' ');

      foreach (string word in words.Skip(index + 1))
      {
        builder.Append(word);
        var subString = builder.ToString();

        if (!matches.TryGetValue(subString, out var sources))
        {
          sources = new List<string>();
          matches[subString] = sources;
        }

        sources.Add(sentence);

        builder.Append(' ');
      }

      BuildConsecutiveMatchesRecursive(words, ++index, sentence);
    }


    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, List<string>> GetResult(int minOccurrences)
    {
      return new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, List<string>>(matches.Where(m => m.Value.Count >= minOccurrences).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value));
    }
  }
```

---

Just for fun and inspiration the below is an implementation using a trie like data structure:

```
  public class SentenceInfo
  {
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Sentence { get; set; }
    public List<string> Sources { get; set; }
  }

  // A trie implementation
  public class ConsecutiveWordMatcher
  {
    class Node
    {
      private Dictionary<string, Node> m_children = new Dictionary<string, Node>();
      private List<string> m_sources = new List<string>();

      public Node(string word)
      {
        Word = word;
      }

      public string Word { get; }
      public Dictionary<string, Node> Children => m_children;
      public int Count { get; private set; }

      public void AddChild(Node child)
      {
        m_children[child.Word] = child;
      }

      public IEnumerable<string> Sentences
      {
        get
        {
          if (m_children.Count == 0)
          {
            yield return Word;
          }
          else
          {
            foreach (Node child in m_children.Values)
            {
              foreach (string substring in child.Sentences)
              {
                yield return $"{Word} {substring}";
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      public IEnumerable<SentenceInfo> GetMatches(int wordCount, int minOccurrences)
      {
        return GetMatches(wordCount, minOccurrences, 1);
      }

      private IEnumerable<SentenceInfo> GetMatches(int wordCount, int minOccurrences, int level)
      {
        if (Count >= minOccurrences)
        {
          if (level >= wordCount)
            yield return new SentenceInfo { Count = 1, Sentence = Word, Sources = m_sources };

          foreach (Node child in m_children.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Count >= wordCount).Select(kvp => kvp.Value))
          {
            foreach (SentenceInfo info in child.GetMatches(wordCount, minOccurrences, level + 1))
            {
              info.Count++;
              info.Sentence = $"{Word} {info.Sentence}";
              yield return info;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      internal bool TryGetNode(string word, out Node node)
      {
        return m_children.TryGetValue(word, out node);
      }

      internal void AddSequence(string[] sequence, int index, string source)
      {
        if (sequence.Length == 0 || index >= sequence.Length) return;

        Count++;
        string word = sequence[index];

        if (word != Word) throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{word}' doesn't match '{Word}'");

        if (!m_sources.Contains(source))
        {
          m_sources.Add(source);
        }

        if (index < sequence.Length - 1)
        {
          string nextWord = sequence[index + 1];
          if (!m_children.TryGetValue(nextWord, out Node childNode))
          {
            childNode = new Node(nextWord);
            m_children[nextWord] = childNode;
          }

          childNode.AddSequence(sequence, index + 1, source);
        }
      }

      public override string ToString()
      {
        return Word;
      }

      internal void Clear()
      {
        m_children.Clear();
        m_sources.Clear();
      }
    }

    private readonly Node m_root = new Node("");

    public ConsecutiveWordMatcher()
    {
    }

    public void Search(List<string> dataset, bool append = false)
    {
      if (dataset == null || dataset.Count == 0) return;

      if (!append)
        m_root.Clear();

      string pattern = @"(?<word>\b\w+\b)(?<space>[\W]*)";

      foreach (string data in dataset)
      {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data)) continue;

        string line = data;
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
          string[] sequence = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["word"].Value).ToArray();

          for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
          {
            HandleWord(sequence, i, data);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    private void HandleWord(string[] sequence, int index, string source)
    {
      string word = sequence[index];

      if (!m_root.TryGetNode(word, out Node node))
      {
        node = new Node(word);
        m_root.AddChild(node);
      }

      node.AddSequence(sequence, index, source);
    }

    public IEnumerable<SentenceInfo> GetResult(int wordCount = 2, int minOccurrences = 2)
    {
      return m_root.Children.Values.SelectMany(n => n.GetMatches(wordCount, minOccurrences));
    }
  }
```

As a bonus I've added the possibility to change both how many consecutive words and how many occurrences to search for.

It isn't that well tested, so don't hang me, if...

Comment: Great feedback. I will have to give your trie implementation a try and get back to you. I have a trie implemented for prefix match (char) but not for a word!